# Separate functions for Get, POST, PUT and DELETE in django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using tastypie in my new project to create a RESTful API.
I want to create separate function for each method (Get, POST, PUT and DELETE) and handle different logic in them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `dispatch` method from the Resource, and there create each one of your functions. If you want to do some simple logic, you would place your code after the call to the Resource original `dispatch`. The code would look something like this:

```
def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
    response = super(Resource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)

    # Pass any parameters that you require to the functions
    if request.method == 'GET':
        custom_get()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        custom_post()
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        custom_put()
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        custom_delete()

    return response
```

In general terms it should be enough for your purpose, except if you want to do some more complex stuff with the response.